# Collapsed Navbar not expanding with Bootstrap in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, navbar

I've read through every solution I can find and I'm still stuck. My navbar collapses into my hamburger button fine, but doesn't expand when I click it. I've dropped in collapsible nav examples from Bootstrap and StackOverflow and it still doesn't work, so I'm thinking the problem is how I integrated Bootstrap into my app?

My application.html.erb

```
  <head>
    <title>ApatheticFacebook</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid container-fluid px-5 fixed-top">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <h1 class="col-7"><span class="d-none d-md-inline">Apathetic Facebook</span><span 
          class="d-md-none">AF</span> :/</h1>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <button class="navbar-toggler hamburger hamburger--minus" type="button" data- 
             toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="hamburger-box">
              <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
            </span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsible-btns">
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <%= link_to 'Home', posts_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
              <%= link_to 'Profile', user_path(current_user), class: "nav-link mx-4" %></li>
              <%= link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: 'delete', class: "nav- 
               link" %></li>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

My gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'gravtastic'

gem 'hamburgers', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.3'
```

My application.scss

```
...
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 */
 
 $hamburger-layer-color: white !default;
 @import "hamburgers";
 
 @import "custom";
 
 @import "bootstrap";
```

And my application.js

```
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

I'm putting together my first portfolio and want this to be a marquee project, so I REALLY don't want to give up on this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is your rails verison?

Comment: it's Rails 5.2.4.4